# Programmatically enable versioning on AWS S3

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having trouble programmatically enabling versioning of an existing bucket using AWS SDK iOS v2.1.1. The error is `-[NSNull _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`. My snippet of code that creates the error results from executing the `putBucketVersioning` method:

```
    AWSS3VersioningConfiguration *conf = [AWSS3VersioningConfiguration new];
    conf.status = AWSS3BucketVersioningStatusEnabled;

    AWSS3PutBucketVersioningRequest *versionRequest = [AWSS3PutBucketVersioningRequest new];
    versionRequest.bucket = createBucketReq.bucket;
    versionRequest.versioningConfiguration = conf;

    [[[AWSS3 S3ForKey:key] putBucketVersioning:versionRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

        return task;
}
```

I am probably missing an argument in how I create the `AWSS3PutBucketVersioningRequest` request, but I cant find any examples or documentation that will point me in the right direction. Any suggestions in Java, Cocoa, or Swift are very welcome.  Cheers, Trond

**UPDATE:**

Based on comments I am including the full method and the error output after having enabled AWSLogging verbose.

```
-(BFTask*) enableVersioningOfBucket:(NSString*)bucket region:(NSInteger) region {

    [self setupCredentialsForRegion:region];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"regionkey%li",region];

    AWSS3VersioningConfiguration *conf = [AWSS3VersioningConfiguration new];
    conf.status = AWSS3BucketVersioningStatusEnabled;

    AWSS3PutBucketVersioningRequest *versionRequest =  [AWSS3PutBucketVersioningRequest new];
    versionRequest.bucket = bucket;
    versionRequest.versioningConfiguration = conf;
    NSLog(@"Config %@",versionRequest);

   return [[[AWSS3 S3ForKey:key] putBucketVersioning:versionRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        NSLog(@"Put bucket versioning %@ - %@", task, task.result);
        return task;
    }];
}
```

**Log message:**

```
    2015-06-06 12:09:41.822 connectS3[50137:6337899] Config <AWSS3PutBucketVersioningRequest: 0x600000082350> {
    bucket = testbucket;
    versioningConfiguration = "<AWSS3VersioningConfiguration: 0x600000024bc0> {\n    MFADelete = 0;\n    status = 1;\n}";}
    2015-06-06 12:09:41.832 connectS3[50137:6337899] -[NSNull _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff7724c210
```

**Update 2**

The image below shows the stack trace as the error message has just appeared when I use a break-point and step into each method call.
[image]

**Update 3**
I setup my credentials as described below. This works fine for all of my other methods connecting with S3 except for enabling versioning.

```
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc ]
                                                           initWithAccessKey:keychainStore[ACCESS_KEY_ID]
                                                             secretKey:keychainStore[SECRET_KEY]];

        AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:region
                                                           credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

        /* One credential configuration for each region **/
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"regionkey%li",region];
        [AWSS3 registerS3WithConfiguration:configuration forKey:key];

        /* Default credentialsProvider **/
        [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should [enable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#logging) the verbose logging and post the log. (Please remove any sensitive information from the log.) Also, can you include the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda Thanks for your comment. I have added some more details.

Comment: It is possible that the instance of `AWSS3` is not constructed correctly. Can you share how you are configuring the service client (the section where you call `+ registerS3WithConfiguration:forKey:`)?

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda I have updated with some more info. I don't think this is the problem as other methods work fine. I was wondering if there could be an issue in the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm it is a bug in current AWS Mobile SDK. we will fix it in future release. Thanks for the reporting.

For a workaround, you can add the following line to your `AWSS3VersioningConfiguration` code:

```
AWSS3VersioningConfiguration *conf = [AWSS3VersioningConfiguration new];
    conf.status = AWSS3BucketVersioningStatusEnabled;
    conf.MFADelete = AWSS3MFADeleteDisabled; // <------ Add this line
...
```

Comment: Would you mind sending a comment here when this problem has been fixed in the AWS SDK? Thanks! T.

Comment: I tested the new version 2.2.1 of AWS SDK but this problem does not seem to have been fixed. Do you know if this issue is being looked into? Thanks for your help! T.

Comment: 2.2.1 doesn't include this fix yet, we will fix it in our next release. In the mean time, you can use the workaround mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Thanks that works! When I immediately after enabling versioning requests the status of the bucket with 'getBucketVersioning' it returns 'AWSS3BucketVersioningStatusUnknown'. Is that simply because it takes some time before the new status is updated? Thanks again. T

Comment: We've just release AWS Mobile SDK for iOS v2.2.2 which including a fix for this issue. Could you have a try and let us know if It solve your problem ?

Comment: Late check of your question, but turns out I still cant get this to work correctly. "When I immediately after enabling versioning requests the status of the bucket with 'getBucketVersioning' it returns 'AWSS3BucketVersioningStatusUnknown'." This still happens although the bucket has been correctly enabled for versioning. Could you look into this for me (I am using AWS SDK iOS v2.5.2) ? Thanks.